# VBA code to display message box if value in another cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA...looking for code that will only allow me to enter a value in a column if the value in one or more of the three cells immediately to the left "contains" the word "Other". I've successfully written the code so that if the value in one or more of the cells is "Other" I am restricted from entering a value, but have not been successful in using ISERROR and FIND so that the code looks for text that includes "other". Here is what I have right now...

```
If Target.Column = 15 And Target <> "" Then
    If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Value <> "Other" _
        Or Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 2).Value <> "Other" _
        Or Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 3).Value <> "Other" _
        Then

        Target.Value = ""
        MsgBox "First Select 'Other' value in one or more of the 'Excluded Employee' Columns to the left"
        Exit Sub
   End If
End If
exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use AND, not OR? The way ou have it, you'll need all 3 columns to contain Other

Comment: Because the OP is looking for 1 or more Others - not 3.

Answer (score 1):

```
If Target.Column = 15 And Target <> "" Then
    If InStr(1, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Value, "Other") = 0 _
        And InStr(1, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 2).Value, "Other") = 0 _
        And InStr(1, Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 3).Value, "Other") = 0 _
        Then

        Target.Value = ""
        MsgBox "First Select 'Other' value in one or more of the 'Excluded Employee' Columns to the left"
        Exit Sub
   End If
End If
exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF` with a wildcard to look for at least once cell containing *other*, i.e.:

```
If target.Column = 15 And target.Value <> "" Then
 If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(target.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 3), "*other*") = 0 Then
        target.Value = ""
        MsgBox "First Select 'Other' value in one or more of the 'Excluded Employee' Columns to the left"
        Exit Sub
 End If
End If
```